Measuring integers with a straight edge
Consider the question of measuring integer lengths with a calibrated straight edge.  Obviously, if the straight edge is calibrated at every integer length from the zero mark, we can measure any integer length.
However, is it possible to measure all integer lengths up to some limit, "N" with fewer calibrations.  Some of the early ones are easy to work out.
Number of marks (other than the zero mark) to measure up to some limit:

Limit = 1; 1 mark required
Limit = 2; 2 marks required
Limit = 3; 2 marks required (at 1, 3) -> 2 is the distance between 1 & 3.
Limit = 4; 3 marks required (at 1, 3, 5)
Limit = 5; 3 marks required (at 1, 3, 5)

Has there been developed a general formula for the minimum number of marks required to measure all the integers from 1 to N?

Q.v. perfect golomb ruler.
